# Troubleshooting: Why does luminaire wiring voltage read 1.9V AC when switched on?

Tags: electrical

A 120V AC ceiling luminaire does not light up.  The voltage reading is 1.9V AC when switched on, 0.9 when switched off.   The expectation is 120V AC between the black / white wires.

[image]

After the photograph was snapped I did remove the red wire net and measured at the endpoint of the ceiling's wire.

Voltage measurements at the switch's nodes read ~122V:

[image]

What is the next step to troubleshoot?

Diagnostic questions are appreciated.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? That's not clear to me.

Comment: 1.9V doesn't sound "on". It sounds like induced voltage from a nearby circuit. Again, we need some context.

Comment: @isherwood  Good to hear from you.  OP is updated: it indicates that 120V is expected and a negligible voltage was read.  Said circuit was part of OEM construction in 2004 and has recently failed.

Comment: When the switch is toggled the voltage reading is toggled from 1.9V to 0.9V

Comment: Was the switch you tested a 3-way switch perhaps?  If this was a 3-way light and the other switch on the branch was a dimmer or "smart" switch, it could potentially explain the extremely low voltage as the other switch could be functionally "off" but not completely open.

Comment: I checked: it is not a 3-way switch.  It is on an old school simple switch, as shown in the photo with the volt meter

Comment: Is anything else in the house broken?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine   There are no broken items as it is well maintained

Comment: I believe Harper was asking if other electrical outlets or lights were not working, with an electrical failure it is common for multiple items on 1 circuit to not function or be broken.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason: after more than a decade, the luminaire wire failed to make proper contact with the switch: this was diagnosed / confirmed by measuring the voltage (~1V AC) at the tip of the wire, which is nearest the switch.  Voltage measured at both screw terminals of he switch returned ~120V AC.

By resecting another 1/4 inch of insulation, proper contact between the switch and wire is assured.