# How do I troubleshoot lost voltage in a previously working connection?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci, voltage

I have a garbage disposal that was direct connected to a 15A breaker and working fine. I needed to share that line with a new dishwasher install so I tried to install an outlet.

I disconnected the disposal and connected a GFCI outlet (and double checked that I connected to the LINE not the LOAD and had correct polarity). I connected a new plug to the disposal, plugged it in, switched the breaker back on and nothing. I tried to hit test and then reset, but still nothing (the test button had no travel, if that makes sense, as if it had no power).

I tested the voltage at the breaker and got 118V. I then tested the voltage at the outlet and got 1.4V. I disconnected the outlet and measured just the bare wires and still got 1.4V (probably phantom voltage).

How do I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Is there a switch between the garbage disposal and the outlet (the one that you previously would use to turn the garbage disposal on/off with)?  Did you make sure that the switch was on?

Answer (score 0):

[Troubleshooting: Why does luminaire wiring voltage read 1.9V AC when switched on?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/246659/56573)

I had a similar problem: the wire's insulation was preventing contact with the circuit.  The insulation had to be stripped back 1/2 an additional half inch.

I worked my way back from a luminaire to the switch.  The **issue was verified** by measuring voltage:

1. at the wire endpoint is screwed into the switch  (~1 Volt)
2. at the switch node (~120V)

The expectation was that the wire endpoint is 120V.  Thus its insulation was stripped and the wire was re-screwed back in.  PROBLEM WAS NOT OBVIOUS, as for some reason contact was fine for more than a decade after the electrical contractor installed the original wiring.

Other measurement techniques include measuring continuity to verify that the line is not broken, however, be sure to turn the breaker off.

Comment: Good dupe target!